# Api request working with postman and resteasy but not working in php curl

Tags: php, curl, postman, resteasy

This is the code generated by postman

```
 $curl = curl_init();


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://smsgateway.me/api/v4/message/send",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"phone_number\": \"40404\",\r\n    \"message\": \"whois @akborodo\",\r\n    \"device_id\": 82531\r\n  }\r\n  \r\n ]",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: <api-key>",
    "cache-control: no-cache",

  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
```

when i try it it display HTTP ERROR 500 int the browser, but it practically worked well in postman

Comment: `500` it mean error from server. What is the error message displayed on browser?

Comment: www.example.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500